# web.config redirects only for specific domain

Tags: redirects, iis, azure

I'm stuck with redirecting for specific domains. The setup consists of azure webapps which bring their own domain `*.azurewebsites.net`, I want to exclude those from redirecting. For additional domains e.g. example.com I need to redirect

- to https
- to www
- and no redirection if I enter the correct address `https://www.example.com`

Edit:
I use deployment slots, so I want the same web.config to work when I swap a slot in production.

When I tried to use more than one rule, unfortunately I get server or redirect errors. Should I learn regex better? Here is my first rule to exclude the "internal" domains, but that is already not working:

```
<rule name="ignore azure" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />  
              <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^azurewebsites\.net$" />
                <add input="{HTTPS_HOST}" pattern="^azurewebsites\.net$" />
              </conditions>
            <action type="none" />  
          </rule>
```

I have read the 30 first posts on google but none of those exclude another domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Joses Answer this does what i need:
- I can access the azurewebsites domain while still on the deployment slot
- the production domain will always be redirected to subdomain with https

```
 <rule name="HTTPS and Subdomain in Production" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions>
 <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.*\.azurewebsites\.net$" negate="true" />
 <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\..*" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
 </rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the rule you need is this one:

```
<rule name="HTTPS ignore Azure" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.*\.azurewebsites\.net$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\..*" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

What this rule does is check if the current domain is **not** in the form *.azurewebsites.net, doesn't start with `www.` and if it's **not** requested through HTTPS. If all three "ifs" apply, then it's a custom domain without `www` trying to be accessed through HTTP, so you send a permanent redirect (301) to the https:// version of the requested domain adding a `www` as a subdomain.

It should work OK. Give it a try and tell me.

HTH

Comment: This is pretty much what we do as well. You might also need further rules to ensure that the request is under SSL, and that the host starts with a `www.` in case either of those aren't true. Remember that rules are matched in order, from top to bottom.

Comment: In fact the rules above ensure that the domain strarts with `www.` and the request is under HTTPS too after the fact. No need for extra rules for that. That's the reaseon to use `stopProcessing="True"` in the exact case "lolops" asks.

Comment: You're probably right.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Joses code it does not redirect to 'www' subdomain from `https://host.com` and i still don't know how to fix. Could you give me another hand Jose? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to force HTTPS that is now a feature of Azure Web Apps without any config changes required.

[How to make an Azure App Service HTTPS only](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/11/30/how-to-make-an-azure-app-service-https-only/)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i already know but this is not useful in my case as it doesn't cover redirecting the main-domain to www, and not redirecting the azurewebsites domain as it is in the deployment slot.